# Add method to Ruby's Enumerable module that produces every nth element

Tags: beginner, ruby, iterator

The task is to enhance the `Enumerable` module with a method `nth()`.

The method shall create a new list, which contains every nth-element of the object, when it is invoked.

For example: `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12].nth(2)` shall return `[4, 8, 12]`

Here's my implementation:

```rb
module Enumerable
  def nth(n)
    i = 0
    ordinal = 1
    relevant_iteration = n * ordinal

    self.select do | num |
        i += 1

        if i == relevant_iteration
          ordinal += 1
          relevant_iteration = ordinal * n

          num
        end 
    end    
  end
end

print [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12].nth(2) # => [4, 8, 12]
print "\n"
print (4..12).nth(3)  # => [6, 9, 12]
```

It works as expected and it has passed the unit-tests.

But: My solution isn't elegant. At least that's my own impression.

- Could my code be improved in regard to more compactness?
- Is my code readable and understandable?
- What could be improved?

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer because I feel like you're looking for something more complicated/interesting, but you could also do this with `def nth(n); step(n).to_a; end`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### nth slicing

Perhaps you could use a slice with map instead.

```
module Enumerable
  def nth(n)
    self.each_slice(n).select{|c| c.length == n}.map(&:last)   
  end
end
```

#### unit tests

```
print [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12].nth(3) # => [6, 12]
print "\n"
print [2, 4, 6, 8, 10].nth(3) # => [6]
print "\n"
print [2, 4, 6, 8].nth(3) # => [6]
print "\n"
print [2, 4, 6].nth(3) # => [6]
print "\n"
print [2, 4].nth(3) # => []
print "\n"
```

---

### Rubocop Report

Skipping an iteration should be done like this..

```
 next unless i == relevant_iteration

    ordinal += 1
    relevant_iteration = ordinal * n
```

rather than..

> ```
> if i == relevant_iteration
>   ordinal += 1
>   relevant_iteration = ordinal * n
> ```

General Guidelines:

- use 2 spaces for indentation
- [frozen string](https://www.mikeperham.com/2018/02/28/ruby-optimization-with-one-magic-comment/)
- `n` as parameter name: min length should be 3 -> `takeIndex` instead?

Refactored

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Enumerable
  def nth(takeIndex)
    i = 0
    ordinal = 1
    relevant_iteration = takeIndex * ordinal

    self.select do |num|
      i += 1

      next unless i == relevant_iteration

      ordinal += 1
      relevant_iteration = ordinal * takeIndex

      num
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You seem to have experience with a broad variety of programming languages. I really appreciate your participation here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for this welcoming feedback.

Comment: I dunno about renaming `n` to `skip`. In my mind, I would assume that `skip=1` means "every second element".

Comment: @200_success you are right, skip is not the best name. I would personally accept _n_. But Ruby guidelines stipulate longer variable names.